# Using Facebook FQL to return comment with the most likes

Tags: php, facebook, comments, facebook-fql

I'm using the FB comments plugin on my website and would like to feature the comment with the most likes on the homepage.

I'm using FQL to get comments. Below is an example of what I have so far

```
SELECT id, fromid, text, likes, time FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ="http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472") ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 400
```

The above query returns the latest 400 comments. How do I query further and find the one with the most likes? How can I modify that query to get what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's anything like SQL (I'm not too familiar with FQL), try this:

```
SELECT id, fromid, text, likes, time FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ="http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/472") ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick response. I actually used your answer but modified it a bit.

Comment: ended up using LIMIT 100. LIMIT 1 was only returning the most recent liked. I set it to 100 so it sorts it from a field of 100.

Comment: if you're able to order by `likes`, limiting to one should bring up the most liked, and you shouldn't need the rest then